# Selenium Webdriver with Python - driver.title parameter

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, parameters

I'm new to Python and Selenium. How is the driver.title parameter is derived? Below is a simple webdriver script. **How do you find what other driver.x parameters** there are to use with the [various asserts in the unittest module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html)?

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def test_search_in_python_org(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("http://www.python.org")
        self.assertIn("Python", driver.title)
        elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        elem.send_keys("selenium")
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        self.assertIn("Google", driver.title)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are asking here.

Other driver.x parameters can be found in [documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver) or [source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py).

```
# Generally I found the following might be useful for verifying the page:
driver.current_url
driver.title

# The following might be useful for verifying the driver instance:
driver.name
driver.orientation
driver.page_source
driver.window_handles
driver.current_window_handle
driver.desired_capabilities
```