# How do I fetch the name of browser tab using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am successfully opening a url using selenium and python. Above the address bar in the browser there is a tab that gets opened, I am trying to get the name that tab displays.
For e.g. I opened the url - https://8.8.8.8
After it is opened, tab name appears as Google.

I am trying to fetch the name of the tab i.e google.

Comment: [Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283067/selenium-webdriver-with-python-driver-title-parameter)

Answer (score 8):

Simply call `driver.title`. See below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://python.org')
d.title
# 'Welcome to Python.org'
```